# How to manually burn tokens on BSC network

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain

I have a token contract deployed on Binance Smart Chain and want to burn some of the tokens manualy, thus to execute following function call from some kind of console.

```
myContract.burn(10000);
```

I have ABI and bytecode

How and where can I execute this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `burn()` function has a `public` or `external` visibility modifier, you can execute it by submitting a transaction containing the function signature and the argument value(s) in the `data` field.

One of the ways is to build the `data` field value manually or semi-manually

```
const data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
    name: 'burn',
    type: 'function',
    inputs: [{
        type: 'uint256',
        name: '_amount'
    }]
}, [10000]);
```

which returns

```
0x42966c680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002710
```

- `42966c68` is the function signature
- `2710` is hex value for `10000` (dec)

and pass it to any wallet that supports custom data field (e.g. MyEtherWallet).

---

Another way is to instantiate your contract with `web3.eth.Contract` and execute the function from there. This generates the `data` field for you and if you've configured your web3 instance correctly, it also uses your private key to sign the transaction and broadcasts it to the network.

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(jsonInterface, contractAddress);
contract.methods.burn(10000).send({from: yourAddress});
```